# $|A(n)|<B$, $\lim_{s \to 0^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}n^{-s}=a$ imply $\lim_{x \to \infty}\sum_{n \leq x} a_{n}(1-\log{n}/\log{x})=a$

Tags: analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Suppose that $|A(n)|<B$ and $\lim_{s \to 0^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}n^{-s}=a$ where $A(x)=\sum_{n \leq x}a_{n}$. Then
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\sum_{n \leq x} a_{n}(1-\log{n}/\log{x})=a$$

What I did :

WLOG, we can take $a=0$. Through some calculations we get
$$\alpha(s)=s\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{A(n)}{n^{1+s}}dn$$
$$\sum_{n \leq x} a_{n}(1-\log{n}/\log{x})=\frac{1}{\log{x}}\int_{1}^{x}\frac{A(n)}{n}dn$$
where $\alpha(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n^{s}}$.

WTS : $\frac{1}{\log{x}}\int_{1}^{x}\frac{A(n)}{n}dn=o(1)$

By the Hardy-Littlewood theorem, we get
$$\frac{1}{U}\int_{1}^{U}A(\log{n})dn=o(1)$$
Take $U=\log{x}$ and $n=\log{y}$. Then
$$\frac{1}{\log{x}}\int_{1}^{x}\frac{A(\log{\log{y}})}{y}dy=o(1)$$
Hardy-Littlewood theorem.

Suppose that $I(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}a(u)e^{-us}du=(a+o(1))s^{-\beta}$ and $a(u) \geq (a+o(1))(u+1)^{-\beta+1}$. Then $\int_{0}^{U}a(u)du=(a+o(1))U^{\beta}$

I need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please define $A(n)$ and $\alpha(s)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:$$|\sum_{n \leq x} a_{n}(1-\log{n}/\log{x})|=|\frac{1}{\log{x}}\int_{1}^{x}\frac{A(t)}{t}dt|\le{1\over\log x}\int_{1}^{x}{Bdt \over t}=B$$

---

If signs of ${a_n}$ are alternating, then following would be an easier method.

$A(x)=o(1)$ by your assumption. So, $\alpha(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(s)\ge 0$ as $\lim\limits_{s\to 0+}\alpha(s)=0$. So it will suffice to show that, $\sum\limits_{n\le x}a_n\log n=o(\log x).$ But, applying $A(x)=o(1)$, $$\sum\limits_{n\le x}a_n\log n=A(x)\log x-\int_1^x{A(t)\over t}dt=o(\log x)$$

Comment: By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, there exists $x_{k}$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n \leq x_{k}} a_{n}(1-\log{n}/\log{x_{k}})=c$ for some $c$. I will push it with your hint. thanks.

Comment: can you please clarify which Hardy_Littlewood theorem you are using?

Comment: \Kunnysan I edited it.

Comment: Oh, you solved it very simply. Good!

Comment: Is it true that $A(x)=o(1)$?

Comment: $\lim_{s \to 0^{+}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}n^{-s}=0$ doesn't imply $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=0$

Comment: I am sorry, it was Newman. Go to [page 67](http://www.futuretg.com/FTHumanEvolutionCourse/FTFreeLearningKits/01-MA-Mathematics,%20Economics%20and%20Preparation%20for%20University/006-MA16-UN04-05-Mathematics%20Applied%20to%20Physics,%20Chemistry,%20Biology,%20Computer%20Science%20and%20Medicine/011-MA11-UN03-10-Number%20Theory%20and%20Cryptography/Additional%20Resources/Donald%20J.%20Newman%20-%20Analytic%20Number%20Theory.pdf). But this condition does not hold here. You need $a_n$ to alternate its sign.

Comment: but the theorem looks interesting. Good.

Comment: I think somehow you have to use HLT theorem as you were doing, for the unbounded $a_n$.